# Not returning Decimal

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me why this is not returning a decimal- only Zeroes.

```
Set PercentComplete = (CSCCalled + HospCalled + NoCalls)/(TotalInventory)
```

CSCCalled is an Integer
HospCalled is an Integer
NoCalls is an Integer
TotalInventory is an Integer

In the TempTable- PercentComplete is Decimal(9,3)

The results end up either being a 1 or 0, not a decimal.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Well, let's see. And `INT` + an `INT` + an `INT` divided by an `INT` equals an `INT`

Comment: When you divide integers in SQL Server, your result will be an integer. You have to `cast` the values as non-integers to get a non-integer result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast one value to float in order to get a float result or you can add a float constant to promote every integer into a float. Try one of the following:

```
Set PercentComplete = 1.0 * (CSCCalled + HospCalled + NoCalls)/(TotalInventory)
```

or

```
Set PercentComplete = (CAST(CSCCalled AS FLOAT) + HospCalled + NoCalls)/(TotalInventory)
```